# Replacing an element in a list by another element in adjacent positions

Tags: python

Suppose I have two lists. For example,

`a = [...,35,27,56,87,...,66,...]`

`b = [...,66,...,73,22,87,56,...]`

Let's say that 56 in `a` and 87 in `b` have the same positions.
Thus, both lists have 56 and 87 but in adjacent (swapped) positions.

How could I find the **first** elements (56 in a, 87 in b) in **both** lists and replace the **second** elements (87 in a, 56 in b) in both lists with the **first** elements?

The end result should be:

`a = [...,35,27,56,56,...]`

`b = [...,73,22,87,87,...]`

Notes:

- I don't want to add another element to the list. I just want to replace the seconds with the firsts.
- Finding commonalities between both sets is not recommended as a start. Both lists may have common elements in other differing positions as demonstrated by the 66 above.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Please advise if any extra information is needed.

Comment: Is there something special about 56 and 87? Or were those selected because they occupied adjacent positions? Does this mean your question requires a list where the elements are such that a has ..., X, Y, ... and b has ..., Y, X, ... at the same positions?

Comment: Maybe it good be helpful for you to come up with a couple of [test cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case). You can start with really simple examples (like `a=[56, 87]` and `b=[87, 56]`). Put the inputs and expected outputs. This is also helpful for when you have the working code and you can test if it works with all the desired test cases.

Comment: @BenY The answer to your final question is yes.

Comment: Question: Why did this question receive -2? I'd like to know what I can improve in the future.

Comment: I guess what I've seen with other questions is if there are comments raising the clarity of the question, and details were revealed, the expectation is the original poster would then go and edit their question so that its quality is considerably higher than the initial revisions. I thought @Carlos suggestion was good, but they were not used to improve on your question. Disclaimer: I did not downvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick-and-dirty implementation I haven't extensively tested. It modifies both lists in-place:

```py
def swap_adjacent_matches(a, b):
    prev_a = prev_b = NotImplemented
    swap_idx = []
    # Get the indices since we shouldn't be modifying while iterating
    for idx, (curr_a, curr_b) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
        if curr_a == prev_b and curr_b == prev_a:
            swap_idx.append(idx - 1)
    for idx in swap_idx:
        a[idx + 1], b[idx + 1] = a[idx], b[idx]
```